# ControlsFX RangeSlider is laggy when orientation is vertical

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

When `setOrientation` is set to `Orientation.HORIZONTAL` the movement of the slider is very smooth, but when `setOrientation` is set to `Orientation.VERTICAL` the movement is laggy.

Below is minimal reproduction:

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.RangeSlider;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        RangeSlider rangeSliderVertical = new RangeSlider();
        rangeSliderVertical.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        rangeSliderVertical.setMinHeight(500);
        rangeSliderVertical.setMax(100);
        rangeSliderVertical.setMin(0);
        rangeSliderVertical.setHighValue(100);
        rangeSliderVertical.setLowValue(0);

        RangeSlider rangeSliderHorizontal = new RangeSlider();
        rangeSliderHorizontal.setMinWidth(500);
        rangeSliderHorizontal.setMax(100);
        rangeSliderHorizontal.setMin(0);
        rangeSliderHorizontal.setHighValue(100);
        rangeSliderHorizontal.setLowValue(0);
        rangeSliderHorizontal.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

        FlowPane vBoxWithSliders = new FlowPane();
        VBox.setVgrow(vBoxWithSliders, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setHgrow(vBoxWithSliders, Priority.ALWAYS);

        vBoxWithSliders.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBoxWithSliders.getChildren().addAll(rangeSliderVertical, rangeSliderHorizontal);

        var scene = new Scene(vBoxWithSliders, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Any hints on how to achieve smooth movement when RangeSlider is vertical?

[image]

Comment: What JAvaFX/ControlsFX/JDK versions are you running? This is perfectly smooth for me (JavaFX 21, ControlsFX 11.1.2, Oracle JDK 20 on Mac OSX 12.3, Macbook Pro M1 Max).

Comment: JavaFX 21. ControlsFX 11.1.2. Openjdk 20.0.2. Windows 11 Pro. i7-8700.

Comment: I don't see any lagging with this code on Windows 10 (i7-7700) using Java 20.0.2 (Eclipse Adoptium), JavaFX 21.0.0, and ControlsFX 11.1.2.

Comment: Strange. Maybe I should explain what I mean by lagging: The high and low thumbs are jumping up and down when moving the slider, this is not happening with the horizontal slider.

Comment: I moved all thumbs around. They all moved smoothly. Perhaps you could add a GIF to your post showing the lag?

Comment: The thumbs also moves smoothly when I drag them separately but when I click on the track and moves both thumbs the thumbs jumps. I will look into visual documentation.

Comment: I can notice this issue on my side. (JavaFX 21, JDK 17, ControlsFX 11.1.2). Infact it has another issue of abruptly increasing the range when dragging on track (only on vertical orientation). Horizontal orientation has no issues. Updated the gif in the question for visual reference.

Comment: I hadn't tried to move the entire range, only individual thumbs. I can now also see the issue.

Comment: I have also tested on another pc, with same specs, and on this pc the lagging is even worse.

Comment: I had also not tested dragging the range. Interestingly I can see this behavior only when I'm running the app on a higher resolution screen. (I currently have a lower-res external monitor connected to my MacBook. If I open the test app on the external monitor, it behaves fine. If I drag the window over to the high-res Retina display, I see the behavior described.)

Comment: The only anomaly I see in the [source code](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/skin/RangeSliderSkin.java) for vertical range sliders is that the listeners to the low value and high value properties (lines 84-92) resize the range bar assuming it's a horizontal layout. I don't think that code should even be there; it should simply request a layout and let the `layoutChildren()` method determine the layout of the range bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the `RangeSliderSkin`. The existing code includes the following listeners on the `lowValueProperty()` and `highValueProperty()`:

```
    registerChangeListener(rangeSlider.lowValueProperty(), e -> {
        positionLowThumb();
        rangeBar.resizeRelocate(rangeStart, rangeBar.getLayoutY(), 
        rangeEnd - rangeStart, rangeBar.getHeight());
    });
    registerChangeListener(rangeSlider.highValueProperty(), e -> {
        positionHighThumb();
        rangeBar.resize(rangeEnd-rangeStart, rangeBar.getHeight());
    });
```

See source code at https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/skin/RangeSliderSkin.java

The calls to `rangeBar.resizeRelocate()` and `rangeBar.resize()` are making the assumption that the range slider has a horizontal orientation. (You can see this as only the `layoutX` and/or `width` of the bar can change. Both `layoutY` and `height` are set to their current values.) The incorrect layout of the range bar is rectified before the range bar itself is redrawn in the `layoutChildren()` method. However, I think under some circumstances additional drag events can be processed before `layoutChildren()` is invoked, causing incorrect calculations on the positions of the thumbs.

I have a fork of the ControlsFX repository at https://github.com/james-d/controlsfx/tree/master which fixes this with

```
    registerChangeListener(rangeSlider.lowValueProperty(), e -> {
        positionLowThumb();
        if (isHorizontal()) {
            rangeBar.resizeRelocate(rangeStart, rangeBar.getLayoutY(),
                    rangeEnd - rangeStart, rangeBar.getHeight());
        } else {
            rangeBar.resize(rangeBar.getWidth(), rangeEnd - rangeStart);
        }
    });
    registerChangeListener(rangeSlider.highValueProperty(), e -> {
        positionHighThumb();
        if (isHorizontal()) {
            rangeBar.resize(rangeEnd - rangeStart, rangeBar.getHeight());
        } else {
            rangeBar.resizeRelocate(rangeBar.getLayoutX(), rangeStart,
                    rangeBar.getWidth(), rangeEnd - rangeStart);
        }
    });
```

and have submitted this as [Issue 1521](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/1521), as well as a [pull request](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull/1522).

Feel free to clone and build my fork as a temporary measure until (and unless) the pull request is accepted.

Comment: Hi James_D. Thanks for looking into this. I'm not sure how I can incorporate your fix. I use IntelliJ Idea with Maven (.pom file) for handling my dependencies.

Comment: @droid The following worked for me. 1. Clone my fork of ControlsFX. 2. In IntelliJ, File -> Open and find the build.gradle file from the cloned repo. Choose “open as project”. This will create a new IntelliJ project. 4. In that new project, Build -> build controlsfx. That should create a jar file under the build folder. 5. Back in your own project, comment out the controlsfx dependency from you pom.xml. That should create an error in your module-info.java. 6. File -> Project structure -> External Libraries, and add the jar file created as a library.

Comment: @droid I’d be interested to see if the fix works on Windows. As mentioned, the original problem did not show up all the time for me.

Comment: Thanks. Using what you described in above I can confirm that the Vertical  RangeSlider behaves like the horizontal RangeSlider - smooth and nice.

Comment: Hmmm. Something strange is going on. I tried above method for my "big/main" project, above was just a RangeSlider test, and in this project I still see lagging :/

Comment: @droid Double check you really are using the patch in the main project (you could just temporarily put a logging message in the range slider skin class, for example). The skin class is a bit of a mess imho, with layout calculations being directly performed in response to user input events, which is not really the way I’d do it. See if you can create an updated mre.

Comment: Edit: I think my "new" problem may be related to this "fix" that I also use for the RangeSlider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76889910/java-controlsfx-rangeslider-css-issue

Comment: Yes, I think above is why it is not working in my main main project - I was using the old RangeSliderSkin due to my fix with the High and Low thumbs. Thanks James_D. You got it :)

Comment: @droid I updated my fork to also address the issue you linked above. If you Use the updated version of my ControlsFX fork, you should be able to remove the workaround.

Comment: thanks, I saw that yesterday and removed the workaround :)

Comment: @droid Just to update, these pull requests are now merged into the master branch.

Comment: Great news, thanks for your work.